# Docker: correct way of persisting container data to host

Tags: mysql, docker, volumes

I'm using OSX and running docker over a Boot2docker VM.

I've been trying to figure out how to persist a container's data (MySQL official docker image) to the host but without much success.

I keep receiving an error stating that the /var/lib/mysql directory that the MySQL service is trying to write to is not accessible.

`docker run -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=12345 -v "$(pwd)/.docker-volumes/mysql:/var/lib/mysql" mysql:5.6`

Looking at the permissions of the mounted library in the container, this is what I see:

```
root@mysql:/# ls -la /var/lib/
total 44
drwxr-xr-x 16 root    root    4096 Jan 27 18:35 .
drwxr-xr-x 18 root    root    4096 Jan 27 18:35 ..
drwxr-xr-x  7 root    root    4096 Jan 27 18:35 apt
drwxr-xr-x 14 root    root    4096 Jan 27 18:35 dpkg
drwxr-xr-x  2 root    root    4096 Jul 14  2013 initscripts
drwxr-xr-x  2 root    root    4096 Jul 14  2013 insserv
drwxrwsr-x  2 libuuid libuuid 4096 Dec 11  2012 libuuid
drwxr-xr-x  2 root    root    4096 Dec 24 13:41 misc
drwxr-xr-x  1    1000 staff    102 Feb  4 15:10 mysql
drwxr-xr-x  2 root    root    4096 Jan 27 16:48 pam
drwxr-xr-x  2 root    root    4096 Nov 23  2012 update-rc.d
drwxr-xr-x  2 root    root    4096 Jul 14  2013 urandom
```

As you can see, the `mysql` directory is owned  by 1000 and belongs to the group 'staff'.

My assumption is that the service process running MySQL is probably set to another user (`mysql`) and therefore I get this error.

I've read that this specific issue can be solved using volume data containers, but since they persist the data only until the last container actually uses their volume, It's not a good solution for me.

Am I approaching this in the wrong way?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You're definitely better off using a `data-volume` container, I do the same thing with local `psql` and `couchdb` databases. The data actually persists, it's just not accessible unless you link the volume to a container. To actually force the volume to be removed you have to specify `docker rm -v`, that will remove the data volume if no other container is linked to it.

Comment: Fair enough, I can live with this solution in development environment, but in AWS for example, I'd probably like to mount my 'mongo' container to an 'ebs' virtual drive in the host machine, how will I be able to utilise your approach?

Comment: The data in a data-container is easily accessible from the host - use `docker inspect <data-container>` to find out where it lives.

Comment: @AdrianMouat Since I'm using EBS to store MySQL data, how can I utilise this approach? I need some way to mount the host's mounted EBS volume  in the container somehow.

Comment: I do the same thing on EBS, just update your `DOCKER_OPTS` to point to your mount point. For example, I set `DOCKER_OPTS="-g /mnt/docker"`, where /mnt is my EBS volume.